# How to call jar file method from javascript in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jar

I am making one small phonegap application.In this I added java jar to project.Java jar contains one class which contains one static method.so that I need to access that method and show in html whatever return value I get.
I added that jar file to my build path also 
please help me

Comment: you will need to build a phonegap plugin and access your jar functions from code in your plugin class.

Comment: I don't know the procedure how to do it please tell me

Comment: Sorry that's not something we can explain in a short answer. Start from there : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide and http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins or google for some tutorials (be carefull about old tutos for version older than 3.0). Once you've read the docs, you can download an existing plugin and use it as a model for yours.

Comment: I also need help with this one. I have'a Jar and .a libraries coded natively on android and ios. Now i need to access these library methods from cordova application.

I've been looking for examples but got nothing so far. :/

Any Suggestions?